# Button in listview with custom adapter to go to other pages.App crashes whenever button is clicked. No errors in code shown

Tags: android, listview, button

I am trying to link each button to different pages, however my app crashes everytime i click the buttons. I am relatively new to Java but Im tasked to produce an application hence any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

My StackTrace error

```
01-03 12:44:41.659 4796-4796/com.example.npstudent.catvaccination E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.npstudent.catvaccination, PID: 4796
                                                                                android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                                                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1238)
                                                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1225)
                                                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
                                                                                    at com.example.npstudent.catvaccination.CatVaccinationListAdaptor$1.onClick(CatVaccinationListAdaptor.java:65)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Mainactivity Layout XMl(Updated)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CatVaccine1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cats"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CatPicture1"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/doggo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CatPicture2"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/doggo" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CatVaccine2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Feline Calicivirus"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CatVaccine3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/CatVaccine4"
        android:text="Feline Calicivirus"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button android:text="Find out more..."
        android:id="@+id/BtnToClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

My listview layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#008080">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_catproduct"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp">

</ListView>
```

My Main activity(updated):
(All values were specified but i didnt show all as it was pretty redundant)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lvcatInformation;
private CatVaccinationListAdaptor adapter;
private List<Catinformation> CatInformationList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CatInformationList = new ArrayList<>();

    //add sample data for list(id for the line of info, name,info, description,id set for the image resource file in drawables
    CatInformationList.add(new Catinformation(0, "Feline calicivirus", "Highly recommended vaccine", "Not a lethal disease but commonly found everywhere",c1,ic2));



    //Init adapter
    adapter = new CatVaccinationListAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), CatInformationList);
    lvcatInformation.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

My Setter and Getter:

```
public class Catinformation {
private int id;
private String name;
private String info;
private String description;
private int CatImage1;
private int CatImage2;

//constructor

public Catinformation(int id, String name, String info, String description, int CatImage1, int CatImage2) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
    this.description = description;
    this.CatImage1 = CatImage1;
    this.CatImage2 = CatImage2;


}

//Setter getter

public int getId() {
    return id;

}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getCatImage1() {
    return CatImage1;
}

public void setCatImage1(int catImage1) {
    this.CatImage1 = catImage1;
}

public int getCatImage2() { return CatImage2; }

public void setCatImage2(int catImage2) {
    this.CatImage2 = CatImage2;
}
}
```

My adapter(updated):

```
public class CatVaccinationListAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
private Context CatContext;
private List<Catinformation> CatInformationList;

//constructor


public CatVaccinationListAdaptor(Context mContext, List<Catinformation> CatInformationList) {
    this.CatContext = mContext;
    this.CatInformationList = CatInformationList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return CatInformationList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return CatInformationList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(CatContext, R.layout.catvaccination_list, null);
    TextView Vac1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.CatVaccine1);
    TextView Vac2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.CatVaccine2);
    TextView Vac3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.CatVaccine3);
    ImageView Image1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.CatPicture1);
    ImageView Image2 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.CatPicture2);
    Button Button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick);
    //set text for text view
    Vac1.setText(CatInformationList.get(position).getName());
    Vac2.setText(CatInformationList.get(position).getInfo());
    Vac3.setText(CatInformationList.get(position).getDescription());
    Image1.setImageResource(CatInformationList.get(position).getCatImage1());
    Image2.setImageResource(CatInformationList.get(position).getCatImage2());
    //Save id to tag
    Button1.setTag(CatInformationList.get(position).getId());

    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page2cat.class));break;

                case 1:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page3cat.class));break;
                case 2:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page4cat.class));break;
                case 3:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page5cat.class));break;

                case 4:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page6cat.class));break;
                case 6:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page7cat.class));break;
                case 7:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page8cat.class));break;
                case 8:
                    CatContext.startActivity(new Intent(CatContext, Page9cat.class));break;


            }

        }
    });









    return v;
}}
```

Comment: Any `fatal` error ?

Comment: No fatal error, app just crashes

Comment: you can debug your code or you can use Logcat to print your flow... so that you will get idea about your code flow...

Comment: Initially for the          
Button1.setTag(CatInformationList.get(position).getId());
return v;
}      if I used v.setTag(CatInformationList.get(position).getId());  the listview itself will be clickable not the button. I will do what I can to understand the pathway of my code. Wanted to hear some professional advice as I am pretty new to coding.

Comment: My apologies there were fatal errors present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your XML. In your button widget in the xml, you have `android:onClick="onClick"`

You can remove this property and it will work properly.
For using onClick property in xml, you need to define a function in your java/activity file with proper name and signature. You can read more about in [Android Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents)

**EDITED**
Add this in your getView function in Adapter class.

```
  Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
    switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page2cat.class));break;

            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page3cat.class));break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page4cat.class));break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page5cat.class));break;

            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page6cat.class));break;
            case 6:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page7cat.class));break;
            case 7:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page8cat.class));break;
            case 8:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, Page9cat.class));break;


        }

} 
});
```

Comment: That solved my crashing problem but now my button is not responding to Onclicklistener

Comment: You have put on click listener on the whole list view item and not on the individual item. To fix that, use onclick listener on the button in the adapter class and use position for switch case.

Comment: Can I ask how can I do that? I have been trying for a while but doesnt seem to be getting anywhere

Comment: Please see the updated answer. You can remove the onclick listener on your listview.

Comment: It is unable to resolve "startActivity" after I add it in the adapter class, any solutions to that?

Comment: My bad. Replace startActivity with contex.startActivity .

Comment: It say unfortunately the app has stopped working when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace? Because I was able to run the code without any errors. Also, for replacing startAcitivity I meant CatContext.startActivity

Comment: I added my Stacktrace error at the top, please take a look. Thank you so much

Comment: If i change the getApplicationContext() in MainActivity file to MainActivity.this, the button will work for the first button but crashes at the second

Comment: First,Don't use getApplicationContext() and try to post the stack Trace.

Comment: It works now thank you so much :), there was a naming mistake in one of my buttons and I i just had to change the getApplicationContext() to MainActivity.this in addition to your solution.